# SSIS Generated Files creation date doesn't match table order

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, ssis

So the basics,

Stored procedure:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY ID
```

SSIS package:

1. Get ID into VAR
2. ForEach through VAR
3. get detail data based on ID
4. generate text file named starting with ID
5. rename filetype ext (Same result with or without rename)

The files appear in the folder in the order expected based on the initial ID selection stored procedure. But, if you sort by file creation date they are in a different order. The only way I've been able to resolve it is to add a 2 second delay inside the loop. A 1 second delay does not fix it.

Any thoughts?

The creation date is used by a third party software for loading our files into it's system. The file induction order is a large business requirement so this isn't just an annoyance issue.

Comment: depends how the other party is getting their timestamps. If they rely on an older method (legacy code and all that jazz) then there was a resolution of 2 seconds with the [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) filename datestamp

Comment: Only issue is the sort order is off when ordered by date even in explorer.  Well before it gets to the vendor software.